# Convert double into percentage

Tags: java

How can i convert example 1.07 into 7%, 1.50 into 50%, 2.25 into 125% e.t.c.

My code so far and it's not working:

```
private static final NumberFormat PERCENTAGE_FORMAT = NumberFormat.getInstance();
PERCENTAGE_FORMAT.setMaximumFractionDigits(0);
PERCENTAGE_FORMAT.format(1.07, "%")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```java
double number = 1.15;

int percentage = (int) Math.round((number - 1) * 100);

System.out.println(percentage + "%"); // Output: 15%
```

To convert a decimal numbers to its percentage representation as a percentage of 1 you need to subtract 1 first.

Comment: Your code is not what i needed because 2.25 should be 225% not 125% but i removed the -1 and it worked. the issue is when it's only 1 digit. Example 1.08 shows 108% i want it to show 8%.

Comment: @edithfinch In your question you said this: `2.25 into 125%` , maybe change your question if this is not your desired behavior?

Comment: I'm sorry i got confused. It's correct. 1.08 should show 8%, 1.50 should show 50%, 2.50 should show 150%. So ignore my last comment. I did some change to final int percentage = (int) ((number - 1) * 100); but it give me issues with numbers like 1.07 or 1.40

Comment: Changed my answer to give the correct output.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but 2.15 shows 215% and 1.15 shows 14%

Comment: I think now it should work, I fixed the rounding error.

Comment: Works fine now. I got it before u but ill prefer your solution. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @edithfinch Works fine? strange, I bet that for the input `2.25` it will print `225%`, and not `125%` as requested

Comment: @user85421 The first comment on my answer shows that the question was mistyped, the desired output for 2.25 is actually 225%. Note sure why they didn't update their question

Comment: @Ada I am aware of that, but in a [later comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77530277/convert-double-into-percentage/77530312?noredirect=1#comment136681600_77530312) they state: "*2.50 should show 150%. So **ignore my last comment**.*" (emphasis added) -- Edith: I  think you must first decide what you want and then eventually edit the question!

Comment: @user85421 Thanks, I missed that! Fixed my answer.

Comment: @Ada, just use _[Math#floor](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Math.html#floor(double))_ here.

Comment: Any reader, please be warned to **not** use `Math.floor()`: for example `double n = 1.40; int i = (int) Math.floor((n - 1) * 100)` will result in `39`, not `40` !  ((`1.40` is actually internally saved like `1.3999999...`))

Answer (score 1):

Do not use `NumberFormat.getInstance()` for this.  The correct method for it is [NumberFormat.getPercentInstance](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/text/NumberFormat.html#getPercentInstance()).

Example code:

```
private final NumberFormat PERCENTAGE_FORMAT = NumberFormat.getPercentInstance();

public void run() {
    double value = 1.07;
    String percentage = PERCENTAGE_FORMAT.format(value - 1);
    System.out.println(percentage);
}
```

No need to append a `%` character.  And as a bonus, it will work in all languages without any additional effort on your part.

Note:  NumberFormat is not thread-safe, so using a shared static instance is not advisable. Even a non-static field may be a problem, if a single instance of your class is used by multiple threads;  creating the NumberFormat inside the method would address this.

Answer (score 0):

> *"... How can i convert example 1.07 into 7%, 1.50 into 50%, 2.25 into 125% e.t.c. ..."*

This appears to be *a − 1*, where *a* is the value.

Here is an example.

```java
double[] a = { 1.07, 1.50, 2.25 };
for (int i = 0, n = a.length; i < n; i++)
    a[i] = (a[i] - 1) * 100;
```

To print the value, use the *[Formatter](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Formatter.html)* class.

```java
System.out.printf("%.0f%%", Math.floor(a[2]));
```

Output

```
125%
```

Alternately, use the *[NumberFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/text/NumberFormat.html)* class.
Note, this will multiply the value by *100*.

```java
double[] a = { 1.07, 1.50, 2.25 };
NumberFormat f = NumberFormat.getPercentInstance();
f.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.FLOOR);
f.setMaximumFractionDigits(0);
```

```java
System.out.println(f.format(a[2] - 1));
```

Output

```
125%
```